# Convert (-) and (escape) signs to (_) when uploading files on wordpress media library automatically

Tags: uploads, admin, media, media-library, library

For internal purpose, I'm looking for to convert (-) and (escape) sign to (_) automatically when we upload a file (photo,video,audio) on WordPress media library.

**Example:**

If i try to upload this 2 files :

- network-picture.png
- web audio.mp3

I want to have this result on wordpress media library for this 2 files :

- wp-content/uploads/2018/09/network_picture.jpg
- wp-content/uploads/2018/09/web_audio.mp3

Right now, if we upload a file with (escape) like **(web audio.mp3)** you will have this result :

- **wp-content/uploads/2018/09/web-audio.mp3**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`sanitize_file_name`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/sanitize_file_name/) hook for this.

```
function my_sanitize_file_name( $filename ) {
    $chars_table = array(
        ' ' => '_',
        '-' => '_',
    );

    $friendly_filename = preg_replace( array_keys( $chars_table ), array_values( $chars_table ), $filename );

    return strtolower( $friendly_filename );
}
add_filter( 'sanitize_file_name', 'my_sanitize_file_name', 10 );
```

It will also convert letters to lowercase to avoid conflicts on case-sensitive servers.

Comment: First, thanks for your reply. I added the code on functions.php. After that, i uploaded the file (normal-picture.png). after the upload, the file name display on the library is  (-1). any idea to fix it?

Comment: any idea about the issue?